# RestKit Mapping dictionary properties inside array

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit

I'm working with RestKit it's good so far. But now I'm little bit confused. I know you guys help me about this. Here is my JSON file;

```
"poor": [],
"good": [],
"great":[
 {
        "name":"John",
        "comment":"Thank you!",
        "created": "2015-03-26 18:58:29 +0200"
 }]
```

As you see I have three array and inside a dictionary. I've already mapped these three array like;

**Interface file**

```
@interface ReputationCollection
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *poorItems;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *goodItems;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *greatItems;
@end
```

**Implementation file**

```
@implementation ReputationCollection

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mappingForClass {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"poor"   : @"poorItems",
        @"good"   : @"goodItems",
        @"great"  : @"greatItems"}];

    return mapping;
}

@end
```

**Here is my question**

How can I relate these "name", "comment", "created" attributes in a model using with RestKit. I know RKRelationShipMapping good at this. But as I mentioned before I'm really confusing how should I do. Any suggestion or code samples very welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Be patient... Do you have a model class to map the items in the arrays to? Have you tried adding a mapping and a relationship for it? What happened? Show the code.

Comment: @Wain You say I should create a model and add these properties and relate that class ? Still confused.

Comment: You have a `ReputationCollection` class, so I'm guessing you would also have a `Reputation` class (though it looks more like it should be `Comment` class)